# How do I make multi dimensional in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this array

```
int sequence[2][3][2][2][50][2] = {
{
    {1},
    {{
      {2, 4}, 
      {3, 5}
     },
     {255,0,0}
    }
  },
  {
    {2},
    {{
      {3, 4}, 
      {2, 6}
     },
    {0,0,255}
    }
  }
};
```

Whenever I try to index the first multi dimensional array, using

```
int frame[2] = {sequence[1]}
```

I get this error "invalid conversion for 'int (*)[2][2][50][2]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most of your cells are not used... Why do you need to use such array?

Comment: imho anything with more than two dimensions is complete overkill and much too difficult to handle. Either flatten the dimensions or encapsulate them into some meaningful data structure

Comment: You're using a language that supports OOP, no need to use something as messy as that array. Create classes/structs that will hold instances of others along with their own parameters. There you can go as deep as you like and still maintain a sense of order.

Comment: I'm doing an arduino LED project, and i need to basically write an animation with LEDs. Using an array like this makes it a lot easier to edit the animation.

Comment: No, this makes everything a lot more difficult.

Comment: So I should write a class instead of doing this?

Comment: @JonathanYu Who does understand this array except you? You have a 6-dimensional array, meaning that each one of your `int` value should be surrounded by 6 braces, and most of them are not. Anyone reading this kind of stuff will have a very hard time finding into which array each value is. I think that even you do not understand this array since you are trying to put a 5-dimensional array (`sequence[1]`) into a 1-dimensional array (`frame`) of two cells.

Comment: @JonathanYu If I did not get that wrong, this is what your array looks like if written entirely: http://rextester.com/HIKLR97643 (except for the 5 dimension with 50 cells... ). I am not sure that this is what you expect from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I try to index the first multi dimensional array, using

```
int frame[2] = {sequence[1]}
```

Let's simplify the syntax you use:

```
int frame[2] = {/*list of ints*/}
```

This initializes a one dimensional array of 2 `int`, using a brace-enclosed list of integers.

An element of your outermost multi-dimensional array with arity `k`, is also a multi-dimensional array (with arity `k-1`). It is not an `int`.

So, there is nothing wrong with how you index the multi-dimensional array. What is wrong, is trying to initialize an array if `int` with a multi-dimensional array as the first value.

> How should I initialize it then?

It is impossible to answer because it is not clear which of the integer values within the multi-dimensional array you want to use to initialize.

Here is a syntactically correct way to initialize `frame`:

```
int frame[2] = {sequence[0][0][0][0][0][0], sequence[0][0][0][0][0][1]};
```

It uses the values in the first subarray of the first subarray of the first subarray of the first subarray of the first subarray of the outermost array.

Comment: How should I initialize it then?

Comment: @JonathanYu that depends on what you want to initialize it with. It is not clear which of the integer values within the 5 dimensional array `sequence[1]` you're trying to use. There are certainly many more values than 2 which is how many will fit in `frame`.

Comment: @JonathanYu Anyway, I added an example that is at least syntactically correct.

Comment: The first part of the array is the delay before setting the frame, the middle of the array stores coordinates (up to 50), and the other part stores an RGB value to set these points to.

Comment: @JonathanYu then first/middle/other part of which array? `frame` contains a total of 1200 different one dimensional subarrays.

Comment: If I wrote this as a python dictionary, it would look like this.  sequence = {
{
    delay : 1,
    points : [
      [2, 4], 
      [3, 5]
     ],
     color : {r : 255, g : 0, b : 0}
    }
  },
  {
    delay : 2,
    points : [
      {3, 4}, 
      {2, 6}
     ],
    color : {r : 0, g : 0, b : 255}
    }
  }
};